# Pass list records to many2many field in odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-14

I've created a wiz to get the product which are in the field "catagory_select" please look the code below:

```
class CategorySelect(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'product.group'
    category_select = fields.Many2many('product.category', string='Category')

    def start_search_product(self):
        wiz_form = self.env.ref('product_filter.get_products_form_all', False)
        for rec in self.category_select:
            product_res = self.env['product.product'].search([('categ_id', '=', rec.ids)])
        print('^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^', product_res)
        return {
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'name': "Product Filtered",
            'res_model': 'product.selection',
            'target': 'new',
            'view_id': wiz_form.id,
            'view_mode': 'form',
            }
        }
```

here what i done is i have created a method which returns a wizard but i am not getting a way that how shoud i pass the "product_res" to a many2many field in another wizard which is called the return menu.

"Any help will be appreciated"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set on `context` with **default** `fields` set with your values.

```
ctx = self._context.copy()
ctx.update({'default_m2m_fields': [(6, 0, IDS)]}) # on new wizard the m2m fields set with default on context
```

Comment: Okay bro i got that... But i have another question... If i have this same wizard in menuitem and a button in sale_form and i want to get the records of that products form the selected category to sale order line if one clicks button and if someone clicks menuitem it will go to else part and return the view which is on return part... What to do bro

Comment: And also i have changed the code and i am getting all the products from my search by giving .ids in search method

Comment: @SidharthPanda That is best you can consider as the new question and share your attempt with code with the best way (code/images). for the future someone can get this answer is best what has asked here. so please create a new question I'm happy to answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the product_res to another wizard using context

1/ Update your start_search_product to pass the product_res ids:

```
def start_search_product(self):
    product_res_ids = [p.id for p in product_res]
    context = {'product_ids': product_res_ids}
    return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'name': "Product Filtered",
        'res_model': 'product.selection',
        'target': 'new',
        'view_id': wiz_form.id,
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'context': context,
        }
    }
```

2/ Get the product ids in function default_get of ProductSelection wizard:

```
product_ids = fields.Many2many('product.product', 'Products')

@api.model
def default_get(self, default_fields):
     res = super(ProductSelection, self).default_get(default_fields)
     product_ids = self._context.get('product_ids')
     res.update({'product_ids': [(6, 0, product_ids)]})
     return res
```

Comment: Thanks bro... This saved my lot of time